# How to move Admin Product Edit form "images and videos" section into under "general" section?

Tags: magento2, product, admin, product-attribute

I would like to move the **Images and Videos** section under the **General** section.

[image]

I have tried with **uiComponent** and **Modifier Pool**. These Both methods are Magento's default method for modification product edit form.

I have also tried to move the section from the admin product attribute set setting to move the attribute.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/howdoi/customize_product.html

I have also tried with the move as a block or container, But no success.

Please help me and suggest any way to do it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to the xml form search for the image field and just move it from the "Image and Videos" fieldset to the "General" fieldset.

I think it could also be "moved" from the `di.xml` using `move` directive, but sounds to me that simply extending the layout and moving the field to the right location should be the way to go.

Comment: Please add more clarity in the answer. Because I don't think any method to do that using di.xml

Comment: @VishalKumar Indeed this was my bad, it's not possible from the di. But you should be able to do it the normal way using the layout. May be you can add the details of what you have in your code and what you have tried.

Comment: I have just tried with default Magento version 2.4.0.

I have also tried  with default Magento methods. Please check link
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/howdoi/customize_product.html